# We are facing following error while trying to create package in groovy envirnment on pr2

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we use catkin_init_workspace command, it is showing following error

without sudo:

```
catkin_init_workspace
Could neither symlink nor copy file "/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake" to "/home/pr2admin/r_os/src/CMakeLists.txt":
- [Errno 13] Permission denied
- [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pr2admin/r_os/src/CMakeLists.txt'
pr2admin@c1:~/r_os/src$
```

with sudo:

```
sudo catkin_init_workspace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkin_init_workspace", line 11, in <module>
    from catkin.init_workspace import init_workspace
ImportError: No module named catkin.init_workspace
```

Kindly help us to resolve this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221744/we-are-facing-following-error-while-trying-to-create-package-in-groovy-envirnment-on-pr2/) by [mathpati.nikhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/25204/mathpati.nikhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Could neither symlink nor copy file "/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake" to "/home/pr2admin/r_os/src/CMakeLists.txt":

This error reads like the user you're using does not have a right to write into the folder mentioned. Make sure you use the right user you're supposed to in your team.

Adding `sudo` wouldn't work unless your super user account is configured for ROS environment (see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo) for the reason).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1